# How to integrate different modbus devices on a web system?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I have two PLC modbus devices. These two are different companies.

The first one is that A will return the temperature and humidity. The second is that B will return five values. In both devices, the connection is modbus TCP.

One problem is that the same test software can be connected but the other cannot be connected. One device can be connected using `pyModbus`, but the other device is not working.

I also tested some software and python libraries. List is as follows

Device A

- Software

  - [modbus Poll](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus_poll.html) (OK)
  - [ModScan32](https://www.win-tech.com/html/demos.htm) (NO)
- Python Lib

  - [pyModbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) (OK)
  - [EasyModbus](http://easymodbustcp.net/en/python-codesamples) (NO)

Device B

- Software

  - [modbus Poll](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus_poll.html) (NO)
  - [ModScan32](https://www.win-tech.com/html/demos.htm) (OK)
- Python Lib

  - [pyModbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) (NO)
  - [EasyModbus](http://easymodbustcp.net/en/python-codesamples) (OK)

I don't know the difference between the two devices.

I want to integrate these two into the web system for monitoring, and new devices can be added in the future.

If there is a third device, I have to retest the connection to see which `Python lib` is available.

How can I implement this?

Learn more about the communication format of PLC devices?
Write a set of Python Libs for all devices?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't see any way around this is if you don't control the protocol, library, or devices

Comment: Try finding the root cause. E.g. use Wireshark to compare the requests each tool is sending. Have you checked the slave_id?

Answer (score 0):

Use one library for each, save the data somewhere centralized and view it with a different app. I don't see the problem. Also, have you tried re-trying the connection or reading after a few seconds? In my experience, modbus devices fail every so often to answer (or maybe is a library problem, I don't know) and a retry usually works.

Answer (score 0):

For this, and it sounds like any good IOT framework would solve it, you should send the data from each device separately to one central point, like an IOT cloud solution, then you can build a webapp to view whatever data you have on the IOT framework, regardless of when or if it came in.  Most frameworks will show you the old data as well if its not connected, so you can still display data, indicating it is stale or something to your user.